# Draw residuals for linear, major axis and standardized major axis regressions

Tags: r, model, linear-regression

I have been going in circles trying to replicate a figure from [Warton et al (2006)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1017/S1464793106007007) in R.

[image: Warton et al Figure 4]

I want to highlight how the direction of the residuals are drawn for a presentation and have a reproducible example. I got the linear model (Fig 4A) done, except for the arrows but keep getting stuck with the others. Here is the code for the linear model version, I also posted this code as a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/SwampThingPaul/97e438fc0102675d808009b8b962ea78).

```r
## Warton, D. I., Wright, I. J., Falster, D. S., and Westoby, M. (2006). 
# Bivariate line-fitting methods for allometry. 
# Biological Reviews 81, 259–291. doi:10.1017/S1464793106007007.

#Direction in which residuals are measured. 

#Fig 4a (Standard Linear Regression)
set.seed(123)
test.x=1:25
error=rnorm(25,0,25)
test.y=(5*test.x)+200+error

par(family="serif",mar=c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5),oma=c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25));
plot(test.x,test.y,type="n",axes=F,ylab=NA,xlab=NA,ylim=c(190,325),xlim=c(0,26))
test.lm=lm(test.y~test.x)
test.lm.pred=predict(test.lm,data.frame(test.x=test.x))
lines(test.x,test.lm.pred,lty=2)
segments(test.x,test.y,test.x,test.lm.pred,col="red",lwd=1.5)
points(test.x,test.y,pch=21,bg="grey")
box(lwd=1)
```

Here is the output:

[image: CodeOutput]

Any help would be appreciated to help develop a reproducible example of Fig 4B and Fig 4C. Also trying to add the arrows showing the direction fitted and residual axes.

Comment: I had a go at something similar here https://tonyladson.wordpress.com/2020/10/05/errors-in-variables-regression/